# Spring: parent declaration for jee:remote-slsb

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm using **spring 3.1.2**. I have many `jee:remote-slsb` declarations with common parameters. I'd like to create parent declaration for them. I've tried:

```
<jee:remote-slsb abstract="true" id="jee-remote-parent"
    cache-home="true" lookup-home-on-startup="true" resource-ref="true"
    refresh-home-on-connect-failure="true"/>
```

But I've got error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Das Attribut 'abstract' darf nicht in Element 'jee:remote-slsb' verwendet werden.
```

Is the *parent* feature not active for "syntax-sugar-like" bean declarations such as `jee:remote-slsb` ?